# How many combinations can chmod in linux have?

Tags: linux, chmod

I know there's 0,1,5,6 and 7 for each category of user

e.g. 755, 644, 600 etc

how many combinations can we have?

also, there's this u+755... what is this about really?

Comment: 0,1,5,6,7 = 5 numbers -> 5*5*5 = 125 possibilities ?

Answer (score 3):

There are *4* user-manipulable permissions locations (special permissions [setuid, setgid, sticky], user owner, group owner, other), and each can have one of 8 values.

8 ** 4 = **4096**

Comment: according to this http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html your answer is wrong

Comment: @artmees: ... No, that page neither states nor implies any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 numbers denote **owner/group/world**
Each of them has read/write/execute bits. You are setting these when it comes to the 3 numbers.

So, 000 becomes

```
owner   group   world
rwx     rwx     rwx
000     000     000
```

777 (which allows everyone to read, write and execute the file) becomes

```
owner   group   world
rwx     rwx     rwx
111     111     111
```

644 allows owner to read/write. Group and world to only read.

```
owner   group   world
rwx     rwx     rwx
110     100     100
```

And so on..
In total, there are 8 bits, which can be turned on/off, giving you 8^3. In addition, there are the special modes **Sticky bit, SUID and SGID**, and their various combinations, further giving you 8 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

the unix privileges on directories is categorised by `[User][Group][Other]` each of these have the options of `[Read][Write][Execute]`

so the form is `[User]{RWX},[Group]{RWX},[Other]{RWX}`

so the permissions are `[U]RWX [G]RWX [O]RWX` so if you are familiar with the ***binary representation of decimal numbers*** you can understand that

`755` would be decoded to `[U]111 [G]101 [O]101` so this means `[U]RWX [G]R-X [O]R-X`

`600` would be decoded to `[U]110 [G]000 [O]000` so this means `[U]RW- [G]--- [O]---`

`644` would be decoded to `[U]110 [G]100 [O]100` so this means `[U]RW- [G]R-- [O]R--`

and about the available combinations are `2^9= 512` available permissions
where `2` is the number of available choices `(0,1)` that could be placed in one of the `9` available places

`[U]123 [G]456 [O]789` in the general form.

you can check this [link](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) for further details and tutorial.

Comment: Except that permissions aren't the only thing `chmod` handles.

Answer (score 0):

Every file and directory has their certial set of permissions on User (who owns the files), Group (Group is to which that user belongs and all the users belongs to this group will fall in this category) and Others ( rest of the users and group present inside the system). 
Now each of these categories (User/Group/Others) can have combination of Read, Write or Execute permissions. 
Read - 4
Write -2 
Execute - 1 
So if a file has [read,write, execute] permissions for User and [read,execute] permission for Group and Others both then it is denoted as 
chmod 755 filename
also, chmod u+rwx, g+rx, o+rx filename

Now if you just want to give USER (the first category) permissions on the file as [read,write] then it will be like :-
chmod u+rw filename.

I don't think the command (chmod u+755 filename) you have written is correct.